# How to run asynchrounously 2 sync task with Grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have 2 Grunt tasks: A and B. Exec time of A is 5 seconds. Exec time of B is 10 seconds.

I run this two tasks in pre-commit script. Both are sync, so pre-commit script exec time is 15. I want to somehow combine this two tasks and run them asyncrounously. So this will take only 10 seconds to execute pre-commit.

Is it possible?

This hell doesn't work :)

```
grunt.registerTask('pre-commit', 'Run sonar and jscs async', function() {
  var done = this.async(),
    _counter = 0,
    asyncTasksCounter = 2,
    asyncHelper = function (foo) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        foo();
        _counter++;
        if (_counter === asyncTasksCounter) {
          done();
        }
      }, 16.66)
    };
  asyncHelper(function () {
    grunt.task.run('A');
  });
  asyncHelper(function () {
    grunt.task.run('B');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use Grunt for this. Assuming you're using `npm` I would define the tasks separately and then use `npm` to run them using something like [`shell-executor`](https://github.com/royriojas/shell-executor) (Windows and Mac).

After installing you add the tasks to the [script section](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) of `package.json` then run the script with `npm run [scriptname]`, like `npm run prepublish`.

```
scripts: {
  "precommit": "shell-exec \"grunt sonar\" \"grunt jscs\"",
}
```

There's a similar script [`concurrently`](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently) which works well for concurrent tasks.

The reason these modules are necessary is because the varying OSes handle `&` (parallel) and `&&` (concurrent) differently, otherwise you could do:

```
"precommit": "grunt sonar & grunt jscs",
```

Comment: Concurrently worked ok. Parallel doesn't work. PS Hah, how you know that A and B is sonar and jscs? :D

Comment: Your task description is "Run sonar and jscs async" :)

Comment: Ahah true :) Thank you very much:) No it is not secret, just it is not important info :)

Comment: https://github.com/royriojas/shell-executor should work instead. I'll update the answer.